# Select only those values that are not contained by another line entirely

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, exists

I have a table like

| user_id | thing_id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-10 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-05 |
| 2 | 4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 5 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-04 |

I want to select all things but skip those that are contained entirely in another thing by the same user. So the result should be

| thing_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

I assume I need to play around with window functions and conditions, but am at a loss how to efficiently query this.

Comment: What if there are 2 rows for the same user and different things with the same dates?

Comment: Good point! I think for my purpose it's not relevant if have multiple identical things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`.

For your sample data it would be as simple as:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
    AND t2.thing_id <> t1.thing_id
    AND t1.start > t2.start AND t1.end < t2.end
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BVnhTz3w).

Depending on your requirement, you may change the date conditions to:

```
AND t1.start >= t2.start AND t1.end =< t2.end
```

or:

```
AND ((t1.start >= t2.start AND t1.end < t2.end) OR (t1.start > t2.start AND t1.end <= t2.end))
```

Comment: thank you for this - I was not aware of using exists like this was possible. did some testing and this works just like I wanted it to!